# Syntax question for an English native speaker

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

For the life of me, I can't seem to think of the correct way of asking the following: say one wants to ask which teams/clubs a store carries a specific apparel item in would it be: which teams do you sell these tracksuits for? For which teams do you sell these tracksuits? Or something else? I can't think of a right way to say this. Thanks!

Comment: Which teams' tracksuits do you sell?

Comment: _Whose tracksuits_ or _Which teams' tracksuits_. But it's awkward however you do it.

Comment: I was wondering what teams you have tracksuits for.

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate it

Comment: Go for Bunting’s comment as the answer. If you imagine the store only sells for one team, use *team’s* rather than *teams’*.

Comment: _Do you sell tracksuits? Which teams?_

Comment: You could also say "which team tracksuits do you sell?", where "team tracksuit" means a tracksuit with the colours/logos of a team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What teams do you sell tracksuits for?